# SQL Server WMI Performance Counters

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have been trying to install and configure a SQL Server Monitoring tool and running into issues. The vendor has indicated there is a problem with their tool collecting WMI information from one of our SQL Instances. They are trying to get a value from win32_perfrawdata_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerGeneralStatistics. However, I have indicated to the vendor this particular server is running SQL Express.

Here is my question: Would counters that begin with "win32_perfrawdata_MSSQLSERVER" be installed with the SQL Express Edition?

If they are not installed I need some type of proof to bring back to the vendor.

Comment: This type of issue is usually due to firewalls - have you verified that isn't the case?

Comment: I remote into the server and try using Wbemtest. I cannot find the counter with "win32_perfrawdata_MSSQLSERVER". All I can see is counters that begin with "win32_perfrawdata_MSSQLEXPRESS"